# Calculating MSE of audio MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mse

I'm trying to calculate the MSE of some audio files in MATLAB. My code is shown below.

```
[y1,fs1]=audioread('one.mp3');
[y2,fs2]=audioread('two.mp3');
[c1x,c1y]=size(y1);
[c2x,c2y]=size(y1);

 R=c1x;
 C=c1y;
err = sum((y1-y2).^2)/(R*C);
MSE=sqrt(err);
```

The problem is, when the MSE is calculated, I get a 1 x 2 matrix, when instead I need a single value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One for each audio channel (left/right)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably returning a value for each channel of audio. If you have two channels it will return two values, if you have three channels it will return three values, etc.

**More importantly:**

It looks like your normalising the summation by the number of channels by using `(R*C)`. 
The square root (`sqrt`) is also [unnecessary for MSE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error). (And you've found the size of `y1` twice).

Perhaps use this for MSE instead:

```
MSE = mean( (y1 - y2).^2 );
```

Now it will find the mean based on the number of rows and divide by that size automagically. :)

**Edit:**

If you want the squared errors separately:

```
err_sq = (y1 - y2).^2;
MSE = mean( err_sq );
```